# Dell Latitude 5495 bluetooth does'nt working anymmore since upgrade to LTS 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, dell, 22.04

I'm completely lost and tried so many thing. I don't understand as it worked like a charm on the previous LTS.
Any idea where to search or how to solve such issue?

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:5833 Broadcom Corp. 5880
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e007 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:568c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated Webcam HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2386:350e Raydium Corporation Raydium Touch System
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-06-12 23:43:21 CEST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 4886 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 16590)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 118ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─4886 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Latitude-5495 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Latitude-5495 bluetoothd[4886]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Latitude-5495 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Latitude-5495 bluetoothd[4886]: Starting SDP server
Latitude-5495 bluetoothd[4886]: Bluetooth management in>
```

Comment: https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0cf3-e007

Comment: There is some way to reinstall the associated driver, it often is required after upgrading. Not sure why. I had the same problem with my RealTek wifi. Works fine, I upgrade, now it isn't recognized despite showing up in lsusb, but was able to remove the driver, reinstall, then it eventually worked. May be a good idea to get another USB bluetooth adapter if that doesn't work.